# Pack HTML5 + Javascript files in .exe

Tags: javascript, executable

I would like to pack my files (html, javascript) in .exe files.

The question is - is there any program I can "load" browser in desktop windows?

If I provided not many infos I can add them, just want to know if that is possible.

Comment: But whyyyyyyyyyyy? If you want to open a certain webpage, most browsers can be passed launch parameters to allow this...

Comment: Something like https://electronjs.org/ ?

Comment: @timothyclifford the thing is that users will use offline webpage and want all packed in one single .exe file,without source code on his computer

Comment: @xs0 yes... somehow like that

Comment: I don't think it's possible to produce a single executable without sources from electron / nwjs. However you can generate an installer from these sources with https://github.com/electron/windows-installer.

If you really need one executable and no installation, you can take a look at "Enigma virtual box" to pack the entire output directory into a single executable. This is not the ideal way to distribute your application, as this comes with performance costs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned, you can use something like [electron](https://electronjs.org/) to build your web app into a native app.

You could also look into making a [Progressive Web App](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/your-first-pwapp/) (PWA) as one of the design aspects is to make these available offline.

Those are two great solutions. A third potential is it should be possible to minify and merge all your js/html/css into a single html file, that just sits on the users' desktop that they can 'visit' at any time.

Out of those three I would highly recommend using a PWA. It will give you the best of all worlds.

Comment: Thank you. I found out electron is best solution.